# How do I validate this php form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a simple html form that looks like this

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="pw"><br>
<input type="submit" value="log in">
</form>
```

What I need to do with this is check the values that are submitted in this form against those in a simple database I have created. The database is name is userdb, and in it I have created a simple table called 'users', with two columns called name and password.

I am able to connect to the database correctly with

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Now I'm confused with (probably the most important bit) where I have to validate the form against some values in the database.

I have created a name and password entry in phpmyadmin, for name='eric' and password='123456'.

I'm just not sure how to check it using the form?

Is it something like this?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `userdb`.`users` (`name`, `password`) VALUES ($name, $pw);";
```

`$name` and `$pw` are values that I got from the form name attributes.

It tells me I have undefined variables though so obviously I've got it wrong here.

Any help?

*edit here is the full code:

index.php

```
<html> 
<head>
<style>
#main 
{
width: 700px; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 

}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="main">


<?php 
$name = ""; 
$pw = ""; 
?>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="pw"><br>
<input type="submit" value="log in">
</form>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","userdb","","");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  else 
  {
    echo "you are connnected";   
  }



$sql = "INSERT INTO `userdb`.`users` (`name`, `password`) VALUES ($name, $pw);";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you not defining your variables as `$name=$_POST['name'];` etc.? That's most likely the case without seeing full code. Plus, what do you mean by *"I'm just not sure how to check it using the form?"* Do you want to check if it already exists? Show full code.

Comment: Post your entire relevant code here, including $name and $pw definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST variables are in the wrong file. Take them out of `index.php` and place them in `insert.php` as so:

You're also storing passwords in plain text, which is not recommended. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function if your PHP version is 5.5. Otherwise, use `crypt()` or `bcrypt()`

**Sidenote**: There is a password compatibility pack [**available here**](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for the `password_*` functions.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","userdb","","");
$name=$_POST['name']; // <-- right there
$pw = $_POST['pw'];  // <-- right there

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  else 
  {
    echo "you are connnected";   
  }



$sql = "INSERT INTO `userdb`.`users` (`name`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$pw')";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to check for successful insert, do:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `userdb`.`users` (`name`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$pw')";

if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo "Database updated successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
```

**Footnotes:**

For added security, change:

```
$name=$_POST['name']; // <-- right there
$pw = $_POST['pw'];  // <-- right there
```

to:

```
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
$pw = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pw']);
```

---

**Login method:** (Sidenote: Use the password storage methods shown at the top if possible).

If you want to use it as a login method, you can use something to the effect of:

```
$con = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");

$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pw']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE name='$user' AND password='$pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row["name"]==$user && $row["password"]==$pass){
    echo "You are a validated user.";
    }

else{
die("Sorry.");
}
```

Comment: Oh gets rid of error now, but how do I make it so that it displays whether login is successful? Right now I can type in any old garbage in the form and it wont give an error? I need it to check whether login matches database entries and say success/fail.

Comment: ok I think it's nearly working, it just says Undefined variable: POST in C:\xampp\htdocs\validate\insert.php on line 24 now?

Comment: Oh this is preetty close now I think, except for my bad syntax.

Comment: If it's about the login method, reload it. I made a slight mistake in both of the `mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST...` @granvi11e which read as `mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$POST...` I forgot the underscore before `POST`

Comment: @granvi11e As for how to check for successful insert, look under another edit where it reads **If you want to check for successful insert, do:**

Comment: Another thing I noticed (I was way too tired), is this `VALUES ($name, $pw)` which should read as `VALUES ('$name', '$pw')` with added quotes around the values. @granvi11e I edited my entire code to reflect the changes. Plus, I also took out the extra `;` that wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM userdb WHERE name='$name' LIMIT 1";
```

Then fetch the result and check if the password is equal to the password you have.

Next thing you want is to return something, and also to *actually* log the user in do:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
```

Or store whatever you want^. Then check if that exists in all your other pages to determine if the user is logged in.

**EDIT**: Also it seems like it's needed to add - you're not storing your passwords securely, and you're also not sanitizing your strings properly (against SQL injections). Might want to look into that ^_^.

**EDIT 2**: Oh yeah, for your problems - variables are undefined because you have to get them using `$_POST['']`. Inside the `''`, put the name of the variable you're expecting. `$_POST['name']` to get the name, for example.

Comment: Might want to mention the potential for SQL injection with this code.

Comment: One important thing to add is that passwords shouldn't be stored plaintext in a database. A better practice is to store the password's hash in the database, hash the password supplied in the form, and compare it to the value in the database.

Comment: @Marty Just that? What about the way he's storing his passwords?

Comment: @Shahar I am *far* more concerned about SQL injection than plain text passwords.

Comment: I for one, can't see what this has to do with sessions. Plus, as OP states *"It tells me I have undefined variables though so obviously I've got it wrong here."* How does this fix the OP's undefined error?

Comment: Thank you, ok edited to add the full code. Am trying your suggestion now.

Comment: it still tells me I have an undefined var on line 26 which is the 
$sql="SELECT * FROM userdb WHERE name='$name' LIMIT 1";

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the [PHP Data Objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) handle the data.

I am not quite sure what exactly you want. You want to make a login page or a signup page?

//connect database

$dsn='mysql:dbname=userdb;host=localhost';

$dbu=''; //YOUR DATABASE　USERNAME GOES HERE

$dbp=''; //YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD GOES HERE

try {

```
$dbh=new PDO($dsn,$dbu,$dbp);
```

} catch (PDOException $e) {

```
echo 'Connection failed: '. $e->getMessage();
```

}

if it's a login page, using this:

//check name and password

$sth=$dbh->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE name = ? AND password = ?');

$sth->execute(array($_POST["name"], $_POST["pw"]);

$row=$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($row) == 1){

echo "Correct name and password";

} else {

echo "Wrong name or password";

}

if it's a signup page, using this:

//insert name and pass

$sth=$dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES (?,?)');

$sth->execute(array($_POST["name"], $_POST["pw"]);

Comment: It's just a simple validation page. Yeah a log in page I suppose. Ok I'll try this.

Comment: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user '$dbu'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 

I think because the db has no password? I just made it the default with no password

Comment: sorry forgot to get rid of '', it should be $dbh=new PDO($dsn,$dbu,$dbp);